# SVG filter on inline symbol

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

I am having a hard time applying a filter to an inline SVG symbol. I can make it work fine in a normal external SVG file but as soon as I make it inline with an HTML document, the filtered objects disappear. Is there anything I'm missing with the `filter` attribute? This fails for me in an up to date Chrome 57.

```html
<html>
<body>

<svg style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
  <filter id="blur_inline">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3"/>
  </filter>
    
  <symbol id="filtered" width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect id="a" x="0" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="green"/>
    <rect id="e" x="40" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="blue" filter="url(#blur_inline)"/>
  </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="no_filter" width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect id="a" x="0" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="green"/>
    <rect id="e" x="40" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="blue"/>
  </symbol>

</defs>

</svg>


<p>Symbol with a green and blurred blue box:</p>

<svg width="100mm" height="50mm">
  <use xlink:href="#filtered" x="10" y="35" ></use>
</svg>

<p>Second symbol with no filter applied:</p>

<svg width="100mm" height="50mm">
  <use xlink:href="#no_filter" x="10" y="35" ></use>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting your SVG to display:none will make it non-functional because it disables all CSS.

```html
<html>
<body>

<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
  <filter id="blur_inline">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3"/>
  </filter>
    
  <symbol id="filtered" width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect id="a" x="0" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="green"/>
    <rect id="e" x="40" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="blue" filter="url(#blur_inline)"/>
  </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="no_filter" width="80mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 80 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <rect id="a" x="0" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="green"/>
    <rect id="e" x="40" y="10" width="30" height="20" fill="blue"/>
  </symbol>

</defs>

</svg>


<p>Symbol with a green and blurred blue box:</p>

<svg width="100mm" height="50mm">
  <use xlink:href="#filtered" x="10" y="35" ></use>
</svg>

<p>Second symbol with no filter applied:</p>

<svg width="100mm" height="50mm">
  <use xlink:href="#no_filter" x="10" y="35" ></use>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```